# $n$ successes before $m$ failures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recurrence-relations, conditional-probability

This question has been asked here before, but with a different doubt. I was reading this problem 4i from "A First Course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross.

> Independent trials, resulting in a success with probability $p$ and a
>   failure with probability $(1−p)$, are performed. What is the probability
>   that $n$ successes occur before $m$ failures?

There are two approaches to solve the problem are given. I have problem with the approach using a recursion relation. It is as follows:

Denoting the probability of $n$ successes occurring before $m$ failures by $P_{n,m}$. It depends conditionally on the first result. If the first result is a success, the task is to obtain $n-1$ successes before $m$ failures. Whereas the first result being failure, the task would be to get $n$ successes before $m-1$ failures. So, the recursion relation is:
$$P_{n,m}=pP_{n-1,m}+(1-p)P_{n,m-1}$$ 
Now, two boundary conditions are given to solve the relation, $P_{n,0}=0$ and $P_{0,m}=1$. I am not able to understand how these conditions are coming into picture. For the first one, I have some idea. For the required situation to take place, one has to have $n$ successes in $n+m-1$ trials, so the first condition means one has to get $n$ successes in $n-1$ trials, which is impossible. Is it correct? Can there be any other explanation?

Also, when I apply the same logic for the other condition, one has to get $0$ successes in $m-1$ trials, which seems to me like the probability of getting $m-1$ consecutive failures. Where am I going wrong? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $P_{0,m}=1$ because you are guaranteed to have $0$ successes before $m$ failures.  That is the flip side of $P_{n,0}=0$ where you are guaranteed not to get $n$ successes before $0$ failures.

Comment: I concur. I'm looking at page 86 of 9th edition (2014) example 4j (not 4i, difference in editions?). The printed expression is $P_{0,m}=1$ and not $P_{0,m}=0$ in the question post.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the error. I meant to write $P_{0,m}=1$ only. I am not able to understand how it is coming.

Comment: Can you please provide some more explanation to this? @Ross

Comment: If you are flipping a coin, what is the chance you get three heads before you get zero tails?  Zero, because when you start you have zero heads and zero tails, so you already have zero tails.  What is the chance you get zero heads before three tails?  One, because you already have zero heads when you start.

Comment: I have got it now. It is because, even before we have had any trials, we already had $0$ successes before $m$ failures, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right